# Getting started with WAMP

Tags: php, mysql, apache, wampserver

I'm a newcomer, and I have three newcomer-type questions. I have done HTML, CSS, and have just finished learning some JavaScript. I have installed [WAMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WAMP) on my machine.

1. I know Microsoft has "MVC" as a methodology; is there something similar for AMP applications? When do I use what technology? A book or good introduction tutorial would be appreciated.
2. Is there an IDE that is good for AMP development?

Comment: use php framework `cakephp,codeigniter,YII`, they follows MVC approach. and use `eclipse, aptana IDE` for php.

Comment: Well, I started with Apache, MySQL, PHP all seperate.  I nearly got the whole thing working properly, but than found the "WAMP" server as a single download.  It seemed like a better package to learn on.  I do plan on building my own implementation down the road though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, welcome to AMP development.

Yes, there are many MVC frameworks, like [CakePHP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CakePHP), CodeIgniter, [Zend Framework](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zend_Framework), [Yii](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yii), etc. Choose the one in which you feel comfortable and good to work in.

There are many IDE(s), like [NetBeans](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NetBeans), [Dreamviewer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adobe_Dreamweaver), [Eclipse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_%28software%29), etc. Again, use the one you are comfortable with.

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes, but you have your choice of a dozen or so frameworks to provide it. [Zend Framework](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zend_Framework), [CakePHP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CakePHP), [Yii](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yii), [Symphony](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symfony) to name a few.
2. I've used everything from [NetBeans](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NetBeans), [Eclipse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_%28software%29), [Aptana Studio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aptana#Aptana_Studio), [PhpStorm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PhpStorm) and [Sublime Text](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sublime_Text) in writing PHP code. Pick one that works best for you.